# Media Element Integration into Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, audio, ckeditor, mp3, mediaelement.js

I am running into a bit of trouble the the wysiwig editor ckeditor. While trying to get away from any flash based media players, I stumbled across MediaElement (http://mediaelementjs.com/), which has been suggested as a good alternative for playing audio and video ( http://drupal.org/node/1035630 ).

Is there an easy way to integrate this player into a media plugin? I imagine that there should be a way to swap out a flash based player for media element..?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom plugin based on the flash plugin.

Capitalization matters, here's the style guide: Coding Style Guidelines
http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_3.x/Design_and_Architecture/Coding_Style

Copy the `_source/plugins/flash` directory and rename it, let's call it mediaelement.

Place the renamed directory here `/plugins/mediaelement`.

Then rename `/plugins/mediaelement/dialogs/flash.js` to `mediaelement.js`.

Add your `16px X 16px` toolbar button image to the `/plugins/mediaelement/images/` directory.
I know `.png` files work, haven't tried others.

---

**Config:**
Load the new plugin in your config:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'mediaelement';
```

Add the button to your toolbar config setting `'MediaElement'`

```
config.toolbar_xxx
```

---

**File modifications**
You'll need to change the references to the "flash" plugin name and files. Here are the minimal changes needed to get the plugin loaded and the dialog window to open:

plugins/mediaelement/dialogs/mediaelement.js (174)

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'mediaelement', function( editor )
```

plugins/mediaelement/plugin.js (22 - 33)

```
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'mediaelement',
  {
    init : function( editor )
    {
      editor.addCommand( 'mediaelement', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'mediaelement' ) );
      editor.ui.addButton( 'MediaElement',
        {
          label : 'Media Element',
          command : 'mediaelement',
          icon: this.path + 'images/mediaelement_btn.png'
        });
      CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'mediaelement', this.path + 'dialogs/mediaelement.js' );
```

There are a few tutorials on creating plugins here:
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials

They will give you an understanding of the structure and required elements. I learned this by going through the tutorials while working with a copy of an existing plugin, it took some time, but most of what you need to is there.

The tutorials contain information about creating dialog windows and the parameters used, they will help you understand what's happening in the `plugins/mediaelement/dialogs/mediaelement.js` file.

You can modify the dialog file to contain the fields used by the MediaElement implementation. I suggest that you compare the embed code for flash with that used for the Media Element to see what parts correspond to each other and the modify the dialog file accordingly.

Comment: So all I have to do is to change any reference that previously said "flash" to mediaelement in the plugin.js file? Where do I actually reference the media element player files, in the dialog?

Comment: You need to look at the context for each occurrence of the word "flash" within the files to decide how it should be replaced. The dialog file should be renamed from flash.js to mediaelement.js. It creates the dialog window with the fields you would use for the various settings You'll need to modify it to work with the media element specific settings. It would be helpful if you reviewed the tutorials in order to know what's important for your situation. I'll take a look at the files and add some notes to my answer.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for all of your help! I did actually run through the tutorials on the ckeditor link that you sent over, it just seemed a bit Greek to me. Any notes/files you could throw my way would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Forgot to mention, in the mediaelement.js, there are a bunch of these `editor.lang.flash.xxx` statements. They are used to allow different languages, it uses the correct lang file based on the users language, but you will need to add the words to each lang file for that to work. The easiest way is to replace those segments with the actual text you want to display within quotations. So, `editor.lang.flash.xxx` becomes `"New Text"`.

Comment: Feel free to ask questions if you get stuck. You might want to open a new question about specific problems you're having creating and implementing the plugin, I think your question asking if it's possible to integrate the MediaElement player has been answered.

Comment: Get a little more reputation and you can join chat discussions, you now have 11, you need 20. Might be helpful as it clutters things up to have ongoing comments and they are hard to read and format.

Comment: I appreciate all of your helpful comments, much appreciated!

Comment: Did anyone manage to do this?  If so it maybe worth releasing it to the community!  I was looking for same.

Comment: @RavishBhagdev Yes, if you follow the instructions in the answer and look at the comments you can create your own custom plugin. The original poster was able to do it, they were new and didn't realize that they should accept the answer.